# How to create Parcelable code for object that contains GregorianCalendar

Tags: android, parcelable, parcel

I haven't understood how to create the code needed to implement correctly the `Parcelable` for an object that contains `GregorianCalendar` objects.

E.g. for an object `User` that contains `String name;` and `GregorianCalendar creationDate;`, my attempt is this:

```
 @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

@Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(this.name);
        dest.writeParcelable(this.creationDate, flags);
    }

    private User(Parcel in) {
        this.name = in.readString();
        this.creationDate = in.readParcelable(GregorianCalendar.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    public static final Creator<User> CREATOR = new Creator<User>() {
        public User createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new User(source);
        }

        public User[] newArray(int size) {
            return new User[size];
        }
    };
```

that unfortunately doesn't work

in `writeToParcel()` at the line

```
dest.writeParcelable(this.creationDate, flags);
```

get *writeParcelable cannot be applied to GregorianCalendar* error

in

```
this.creationDate = in.readParcelable(GregorianCalendar.class.getClassLoader());
```

get *Incompatible types* error

How to code correctly the `Parcelable`?

**EDIT**

I have tried some code generators but use different ways and I'm not sure what is the right implementation, the first one use writeValue and readValue in this way:

```
 @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeValue(creationDate);
    }

 protected User(Parcel in) {
        name = in.readString();
        creationDate = (GregorianCalendar) in.readValue(GregorianCalendar.class.getClassLoader());
    }
```

the second one use

```
 @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeString(name);
            dest.writeSerializable(creationDate);
        }

     protected User(Parcel in) {
            name = in.readString();
            creationDate = (GregorianCalendar) in.readSerializable();
        }
```

**What is the right way?**

Comment: have you tried using http://www.parcelabler.com/ ?

Comment: No but I have tried to use a parcelable code generator plugin but creates wrong code. The site that you have linked use

 `creationDate = (GregorianCalendar) in.readValue(GregorianCalendar.class.getClassLoader());`
and 
 `dest.writeValue(creationDate);` could you confirm that is the right way to Parcel GregorianCalendar?

Comment: see Calendar.getTimeInMillis/Calendar.setTimeInMillis

Comment: @pskink what do you mean?

Comment: just parcel the long millis value

Comment: To use millis I have to change too much codelines. I prefer to use a valid way to parcel GregorianCalendar. Anyway I haven't understood the reason why using millisecond should be a better way according to you.

Comment: he is right, if you can't send the object over then just get the date out in milis (long) and send that over in the parcel.

Comment: I have no doubt that also the millisecond could be used in some way, but I want to Parcel `GregorianCalendar` to avoid to change others already coded methods. Someone could tell me what is the righ way to Parcel `GregorianCalendar`? What about the 2 different methods in the EDIT? Are valid? If yes what shoud I use?

Comment: who has downvoted the question? what is the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the second way since `GregorianCalendar` implements `Serializable`, and the `Parcelable` will work.

```
      @Override
      public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeString(name);
            dest.writeSerializable(creationDate);
      }

     protected User(Parcel in) {
            name = in.readString();
            creationDate = (GregorianCalendar) in.readSerializable();
     }
```

However **you MUST NOT serialize GregorianCalendar**, because updates in `GregorianCalendar` related class can cause issue. Consider the case you load a file that contains `GregorianCalendar` objects created with a different API version, the difference in `GregorianCalendar` implementation will lead to sure errors, is enough a little difference in `serialVersionUID` costant to prevent the correct load of the file.

Use `long` parameters to store the millisecond of the date, if you don't want to rewrite your whole application you can easily create a couple of methods to convert from millis to `GregorianCalendar` and vice-versa as you need.